# Why don't moving observers visually see their objects contract in length?

Tags: special-relativity, optics

I have what I think is a very elementary question about special relativity.

Suppose observer B is moving relative to observer A.  If B is holding a rod that is oriented along the direction of motion, then A will observe B's rod to be shorter than normal.  From B's perspective, the rod is the same size as always and he can even prove that by measuring the rod with a ruler.  Now from A's perspective, what's going on is that both B's ruler and B's rod are contracted by the same amount, so that is leading B to the incorrect conclusion that the rod isn't shorter than usual.

But measuring the rod with a ruler isn't the only tool at B's disposal.  B can also just look at the rod with his eyes, and he can see that it looks the same as always, it doesn't look shorter than normal.  My question is, from A's perspective what is the reason that the rod doesn't visually look shorter to B? That is, why does the rod look longer to B than it really is (according to A)?

Would answering this require an analysis of human vision, or is it simpler than that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71414/discussion-on-question-by-keshav-srinivasan-why-dont-moving-observers-visually).

Answer (score 2):

> so that is leading B to the incorrect conclusion that the rod isn't shorter than usual.

What makes you think this conclusion is incorrect?  Relativity is telling you that the conclusion is, in fact, *correct* — it's just that the definition of length depends on the state of motion relative to the object being measured.  Both A and B are considered correct.  They have different results for their measurements of the physical extents of objects because, as Einstein told us, such measurements are **relative**.

> B can also just look at the rod with his eyes, and he can see that it looks the same as always, it doesn't look shorter than normal.

While this is true because of the invariance of the speed of light and the principle of relativity, I would caution you against confusing the trajectories of photons with the inherent shape of an object.  See wikipedia's section on the special relativity page [about measurement versus appearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Measurement_versus_visual_appearance).

> My question is, from A's perspective what is the reason that the rod doesn't visually look shorter to B? That is, why does the rod look longer to B than it really is (according to A)?

Because A believes the theory of relativity, and understands that the relative motion of observers must be incorporated into any such calculations.

I think the easiest way to understand the fundamental mistake you are making is by looking at the relativity of simultaneity.  When either A or B measures the length of the rod, they measure the distance between the two ends of the rod *simultaneously*.  But they "disagree" on the simultaneity whenever two events take place at different spatial locations — unless of course they account for the simple fact that simultaneity itself is a relative concept, and depends on their relative state of motion.

Imagine two photons that bounced off the opposite ends of the rod "simultaneously" according to B.  The photons hit B's eye at (very nearly) the same spatial location, so both A and B agree that those two photons hit the eye (very nearly) simultaneously.  But in A's frame one had to be emitted much earlier than the other, because it had farther to go to reach the eye at that moment.  So the very relevance of this issue is questionable.

Ultimately, there are numerous phenomena that you could analyze.  In good old Galilean relativity, things were easy because the same numbers (like length) would appear in many contexts (like comparing to a ruler or predicting the angle subtended by visual measurement), no matter who you asked.  It turns out that's just not good enough when dealing with speeds comparable to the speed of light, so you need *special* relativity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71415/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-why-dont-moving-observers-visually-see-their-objec).

Answer (score 2):

> **from A's perspective what is the reason that the rod doesn't visually look shorter to B?**

A observes that the rod is *not* moving relative to B, this explains the length reported by B to A.

A observes that the rod *is* moving relative to A, this explains the difference in the lengths observed by A and reported by B.

A and B are happy and are in agreement. A can calculate the length of the rod in B's frame of reference and note that this calculation matches the measured length reported by B. Similarly, B can calculate the length of the rod in A's frame of reference and verify that the calculated value matches the measured length reported by A. All is as it should be. The universe is operating in accordance with both their expectations.

> **why does the rod look longer to B than it really is (according to A)?**

It doesn't look longer than it really is.

Its length is not a single constant value. Its actual length depends on the frame of reference of the observer, as all observers know and expect. None of its observed lengths are any less real than any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

It's the principle of relativity. If it didn't look the exact same to him as if he were stationary, he would've invalidated the principle that "the laws of physics are the same in every inertial frame".

Put another way, he would have discovered a way to determine his speed relative to *you*, without taking any reference points, e.g. he has determined an absolute speed.  But then if it's not with reference to you, then it should equally hold true for another observer, in motion relative to you.  But he can't determine a different *absolute* length contraction for every possible observer, because this isn't consistent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71413/discussion-on-answer-by-cdcm-why-dont-moving-observers-visually-see-their-objec).